# Get textarea value once a key pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have an function executed after a keypress event :

```
$("#txtarea").keypress(function(){
    alert(document.getElementById("txtarea").value);
});
```

I want to return the new text of the textarea after every keypress, so that it can be used simultanuously in other javascript functions.

The problem with this script is that once a key is pressed, the function displays "" empty string.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keypress just get fired before the value assigned.
Like every other event(click, submit etc'...) so you can cancel the default behavior and "stuff"

```
$('#txtarea').keypress(function(event) {
    return false; // this will disable the new value assignment
});
```

You can find out what button was clicked with event.which and work with it.

Example:

```
<input id="txtarea" />​

$('#txtarea').keypress(function(e){
    var value = this.value; 
    alert(value);
    alert(value + String.fromCharCode(e.which))
})​;
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VtWCd/)**

**You can also use the `keyup` event, but it has other meaning and usage than `keypress`.

Be aware!**

Comment: thank you friend, Your answer what useful, But I've used keyup (and I know what's it for)... thank you again +1 :)))

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `keyup` instead of `keypress`

Comment: `keyup` has other meaning and usage than `keypress`.

Comment: tank you my friend , this also has been usefull.. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code, note keyup rather than keypress as this means the key has been added to the textarea:

```
​$('#txtarea').keyup(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});​​​​​​​
```

Also, no need to do the document.getElementById, just use `this.value`

http://jsfiddle.net/A8XxK/1

Comment: `keyup` has other meaning and usage than `keypress`.

Comment: Thank you friend, +1 ...this was useful

Answer (score 0):

Perform the behaviour after a zero-length timeout.

```
$("#txtarea").keypress(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(document.getElementById("txtarea").value);
    }, 0);
});
```