# Textarea first char doesn't show with textarea .val()

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea and I am trying to get its value. It's all ok except that the first char doesn't show it self in the `textarea.val()`. The code is simple like :

```
var content = $('textarea');
content.keypress(function() {
       console.log(content.val());
})
```

If I type 'abc' in the console i shown:

```
      (empty line)
a
ab
```

And it should be (what i expect):

```
a
ab
abc
```

Why is this behaviour or i misunderstood something?

Comment: `keypress` happens before the letter is typed into the textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get textarea value once a key pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723896/get-textarea-value-once-a-key-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyup` method instead of `keypress`

```js
var content = $('textarea');
content.keyup(function() {
  console.log(content.val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

`keypress` is fired when the key is pressed down, `keyup` is fired when the key is released